# how to get value of two tags of xml using sed

Tags: xml, sed, tags

I have an xml files and I want to fetch the values of some tags.
XML is something like this given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone = "no"?>
<!DOCTYPE handover_list PUBLIC"EN""h">
<X1>
<X2>
<X3>USA</X3>
<date_time>20170813T18:18-04:00</date_time>
<id action="I">XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</id>
<id action="I">YYYYYYYYYYYYYY</id>
<id action="I">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</id>
</X2>
<X2>
<X3>UAE</X3>
<date_time>20160814T15:15-03:04</date_time>
<id action="I">AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</id>
<id action="I">BBBBBBBBBBBBBB</id>
<id action="I">CCCCCCCCCCCCCC</id>
</X2>
</X1>
```

What I'm using is:

```
sed -n 's:.*<X3>\(.*\)</X3>.*:\1:p' formated.xml
sed -n 's:.*<id action="I">\(.*\)</id>.*:\1:p' formated.xml
```

and its given output like this:

```
USA
UAE
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

What I want is to merge both the sed commands used above so that I can get the output like this:

```
USA
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is using xml parsers like [**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

In such case, `<DOCTYPE ..>` tag is redundant.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//X2/*[not(self::date_time)]' -n formated.xml
```

The output:

```
USA
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate both sed commands with one `;`:

```
sed -n 's:.*<X3>\(.*\)</X3>.*:\1:p' formated.xml
sed -n 's:.*<id action="I">\(.*\)</id>.*:\1:p' formated.xml
```

To one sed command:

```
sed -n 's:.*<X3>\(.*\)</X3>.*:\1:p; s:.*<id action="I">\(.*\)</id>.*:\1:p' formated.xml
```

Output:

```
USA
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: +1. It's important to understand that sed reads the input stream into the pattern space one line at a time, executing every command for that line of input before reading the next line from the pattern space.  Sed piped to sed is different than a string of sed commands executed in one sed invocation.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed:

```
sed '/<X3>/{s/<[^>]*>//g;h};/ action=/{s/<[^>]*>//g;H};/<\/X2>/{g;b};d' formated.xml
```