# grep a word of some length and pick the n lines below it untill the same length word is found

Tags: shell, grep, lines, cpu-word

I have a text file in unix environment containing data and I'm performing some operations on that file using shell script to get some specific data. File data is like this:

```
USA
11111111111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222
33333333333333333333333333
UAE
44444444444444444444444444
55555555555555555555555555
77777777777777777777777777
66666666666666666666666666
88888888888888888888888888
USA
99999999999999999999999999
10101010101010101010101010
20202020202020202020202020
50050505050005050505050505
USA
20020202022222020222220202
30303333033030333030303330
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
NAE
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
```

I want to get the numbers present below UAEs. i.e. I'm expecting output like this:
Expected Output:

```
UAE
44444444444444444444444444
55555555555555555555555555
77777777777777777777777777
66666666666666666666666666
88888888888888888888888888
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Comment: You can try to split your string by new line character, then look for string you need to find in array and then using loop get some elements after that

Comment: With [your xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45689805/3776858): `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//X1/X2[X3='UAE']" -v 'X3' -n -v 'id' -n file.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` to attain your goal,

```
$ awk 'length($0)==3{a=($0=="UAE")?1:0}a' file
```

Brief explanation,

- Use flag `a` to determine if a record is printed
- While `length($0)==3`, if and only if `$0=="UAE"`, set a=1, otherwise a=0
- If `length($0)!=3`, keep what `a` used to be.

Comment: Nice ++ (this is a filler).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v s=UAE '$0==s||p{p=(length($0)==length(s)?$0==s:p)}p' file
UAE
44444444444444444444444444
55555555555555555555555555
77777777777777777777777777
66666666666666666666666666
88888888888888888888888888
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v s=UAE '                          # pass the string as variable
    $0==s||p {                            # enable p rinting if s tring matches
        p=(length($0)==length(s)?$0==s:p) # non-matching samelength string disables p 
    }
    p' file
```

**Edit:** Another one in awk:

```
$ awk -v s=UAE '$0==s||length($0)==length(s)&&$0!=s&&p{p=$0==s}p' file
UAE
44444444444444444444444444
55555555555555555555555555
77777777777777777777777777
66666666666666666666666666
88888888888888888888888888
UAE
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```